# how to avoid .flatMap(x-> reactiveAction(x).thenReturn(x))

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, project-reactor, publisher

During some reactive programming in Java using project reactor library, I stumbled upon a pattern for which I'm wondering if there is out of box support?

So I want the code below:

```
Mono.just("hello")
    .flatMap(hello -> reactiveAction(hello).thenReturn(hello))
    ..
    .;
```

to be turned into something like:

```
Mono.just("hello")
    .coolOperation(this::reactiveAction)
    ..
    .;
```

I can not use doOnNext because what I want to do inside reactiveAction is not side effect. 
and reactive action is:

```
Mono<Integer> reactiveAction(String text){
  return ....
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a nice feature request. You might open an issue in the Reactor GitHub repository.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Do you still insist on your comment that it is not possible? I think that the `Mono#delayUntil()` pretty well answer the question and it has been accepted.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Nope, I was wrong. Always happy to be wrong, I had no idea this operator existed until this question :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerry So shall you delete it (so as not to confuse other readers :) ) and then we will remove this conversation? :) You with your 64k reputation might confuse some readers. Even Simon "Mr. Reactor" Baslé's original answer was not ideal :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered `Mono#delayUntil`?

```java
Mono.just("hello")
    .delayUntil(hello -> reactiveAction(hello))
    ..
    .;
```

Comment: I wrote a test and apparently delayUntil satisfies my requirements. @bsideup are there any special considerations about delayUntil that I need to consider before using it? you know sometimes reactive functions are not to be just easily used.

Comment: `delayUntil` fits your use case well and there isn't anything to consider before using it :)

Comment: @MahdiAmini "you know sometimes reactive functions are not to be just easily used" - oh how terribly right you are! :) Anyway, thanks a lot for your question, I also overlooked the existence of the `Mono#delayUntil` method!

Answer (score 1):

I can't find built-in solution, but you could create utility function:

```
public static <T> Function<Mono<T>, Publisher<T>> coolOperation(
        Function<T, Mono<?>> companionMonoFunction) {
    return originalMono -> originalMono
            .flatMap(t -> companionMonoFunction.apply(t)
                    .thenReturn(t));
}
```

And now you can use it with `transform` or `transformDeffered`:

```
Mono.just("hello")
    .transform(coolOperation(this::reactiveAction))
    ...;
```

But for me it doesn't look much prettier :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see @bsideup answer, looks like `delayUntil` could fit the bill.

My original answer as an alternative suggestion:

> I don't think there is any baked-in syntactic sugar to do this, as the *"perform an async operation that depends on the original `onNext`"* is the very definition of `flatMap`. We actually added the `thenReturn(foo)` as syntactic sugar over `.then(Mono.just(foo))`.
>
> If you want to further shorten the code, offer an alternative to `reactiveAction` that also returns the original value:
>
> ```
> Mono<String> reactiveActionBackground(String text){
>   return reactiveAction(text).thenReturn(text);
> }
> ```
>
> which can then be invoked directly on `flatMap` rather than through `transform`:
>
> ```
> Mono.just("hello")
>     .flatMap(this::reactiveActionBackground);
> ```